# Buttons stretching in GridView

Tags: android, button, gridview

I have a Grid View and a Custom Adapter to create a variable number of buttons. All have them should keep the ratio of their common background (a square).

But my problem is that I cant get my Grid View to stretch them keeping their "ratio" height/width. They are not squares at all..

The best would be that they keep all squared and resized to fullfill the screen.

Here is my Adapter code

```
 public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return size*size;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button btn;
        if (convertView == null) {
            btn = new Button(mContext);
            btn.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        }
        else {
            btn = (Button) convertView;
        }

        btn.setId(position);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.undiscovered);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position));
        return btn;
    }
}
```

and here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.gabriel.minesweeper.GameActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/GameTextview"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ImageButton` class (which extends `Button`), we can get what you want like so... (Scroll to the bottom for the full code sample)

#### Get the width of the parent `View`, in your case that is the `GridView`

```
double parentWidth = ((MainActivity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.gridview).getWidth();
```

#### Get the buttons image dimensions

```
double width = button.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
double height = button.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
```

#### Calculating scaling factors for proportional scaling in the X-Axis

For *proportional scaling* `scalex` wants to be `= 1` and `scaley` wants to be the ratio between the image width and the width of the parent `View`. We calculate this like:

```
double scalex = parentWidth / parentWidth;
double scaley = parentWidth / width;
```

#### Calculate the new dimensions using the scaling factor

```
int newWidth = (int) (width * scalex);
int newHeight = (int) (height * scaley);
```

For a *square* `ImageButton` use this code:

```
int newWidth = (int) parentWidth;
int newHeight = (int) parentWidth;
```

#### ImageButton scaling type

The scale type `CENTER_INSIDE` ensures an image is displayed central with respect to the `ImageButton` and that it is displayed at full size without distortion.

```
button.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

---

#### Here's it all together:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ImageButton button;
    if (convertView == null) {
        button = new ImageButton(mContext);
        button.setPadding(2,2,2,2);

    } else {
        button = (ImageButton) convertView;
    }


    button.setId(position);
    button.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    button.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    //Scale button using layout params
    double parentWidth = ((MainActivity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.gridview).getWidth();
    double width = button.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    double height = button.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    double scalex = parentWidth / parentWidth;
    double scaley = parentWidth / width;
    int newWidth = (int) (width * scalex);
    int newHeight = (int) (height * scaley);

    button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight));

    return button;
}
```

[image: Proportional Scaling]